# why adding media change some properties of the element?

Tags: html, css

I have started my first template with CSS and HTML. I was watching a tutorial for creating some of the mainline templates.
The code was very simple.
The HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
}
```

When he decreased the size of the page from the browser, a horizontal scroll bar has appeared and the text did not wrap.
after adding this media the scroll bar has disappeared and the text wrapped.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
```

Why the scroll bar disappeared after adding the media?

[image: the image is without media]

[image: The image is with media]

Comment: Can you clarify is the scroll bar dis appeared or appeared after adding the media?

Comment: The scroll bar has appeared before adding the media. The scroll bar I am talking about is the horizontal one not the vertical.

Comment: What happen after adding media to the scroll bar? Because you question in the post is `Why the scroll bar appeared after adding the media?`

Comment: yeah, I am really sorry about that. I noticed that mistake and I edited the post.

Comment: "after adding this media the scroll bar has appeared and the text wrapped." are you sure that in this case there was a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: I have included some images in the question to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

(The code you have provided won't exhibit that behaviour. See the end of this answer.)

If the element is too wide for the window, then a scrollbar will be added so you can scroll to see the whole element.

Media queries let you specify different CSS to be applied depending on properties of the media.

This allows you to say "If the window is wider (or narrower) than X set the width of the element to Y". This means you can change the width of the element so when the window is narrower, the element is also narrower, so it still fits in the window and a scrollbar isn't needed to view the whole thing. Since a scrollbar isn't needed, one isn't added.

However, in your code you won't see that effect because the `.container` element is at its smallest width if none of the media queries apply. I can only assume that the default width for `.container` was changed at the same time the media queries were added.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answer. `.container` has a bigger width it was 600px not 300px.